# UV Wrap or Bake Normals first?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I wanted to texture paint this high poly object (left).  I've created a low poly version (right).  My question is; do I have to UV unwrap it first ***then*** bake the normals... and if so do I unwrap the high poly or low poly version?

Been searching for a while on the best way to do this so any tutorials would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Baking won't work without unwrapping. So yes, unwrap is done before baking for object you're baking to (lowpoly).

Answer (score 2):

You must unwrap the low poly version first. That is how your bake will have coordinates to match up from low poly to high poly. If you tried to bake normals first, you would get an error because the program would not know where to put them in your image.

Comment: Sweet thank you very much!  Once I've unwrapped the low poly, do i need to bake high\low on top of each other or can it be done side by side?

Comment: You should have them in the same space so that the rays can intersect both.